# Problems with casting a class to a player

Tags: java, minecraft, bungeecord

I was working on a bungeecord plugin, when i ran into a issue.
I was working with this [API](https://github.com/Simonsator/BungeecordPartyAndFriends/wiki/API) , when i ran into an issue.
To obtain the PlayerParty object i need to use this method

```
PartyManager.getInstance().getParty()
```

But it takes in a OnlinePAFPlayer, so i tried this:

```
OnlinePAFPlayer player = (OnlinePAFPlayer) sender;
PartyManager.getInstance().getParty(player)
```

But this didn't work, and i got this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: net.md_5.bungee.UserConnection cannot be cast to de.simonsator.partyandfriends.api.pafplayers.OnlinePAFPlayer

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Well, restating what the error message says, a `UserConnection` (which is the type of your `sender` variable) cannot be cast to an `OnlinePAFPlayer`.  You can't just change any object into any other object, how could the compiler possibly know how to do that?  There must be a way to get a properly initialized `OnlinePAFPlayer` within that API.  I suggest reading that API's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your exception is that the class OnlinePAFPlayer does not extend from `UserConnection` or that there is a conversion method given in the API, which is the type of your `sender`-object.

To get a `PAFPlayer` you can use  `PAFPlayerManager.getInstance().getPlayer("Notch")`. If the player is online you can cast it to `OnlinePAFPlayer`. Alternatively you can convert `ProxiedPlayer`-objects to `OnlinePAFPlayer`'s, similar to the method above.

I'd suggest you try to convert your `sender`-object to ProxiedPlayer first, then convert it using the method mentioned above :)